# Does Fourier Series have any application related to computer science?

Tags: math, computer-science, linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

We have Fourier Series and several other chapters like Fourier Integral and Transforms, Ordinary Differential Equations, Partial Differential Equations in my Course.

I am pursuing Bachelors Degree in Computer Science & Engineering. Never being fond of mathematics I am little curios to know where this can be useful for me.

Comment: If you ask this question the chances are high differential equations will never be useful to you. It is still wise to get a general understanding of these things to know what e.g. compression or signal processing algorithms are based on.

Comment: FFT is fundamental in computer science as it provides speedup to many algorithms (that would run for ever otherwise). For example big numbers multiplication without FFT for very big numbers (like in CS)  is impractical. Many CV and DIP and Signal processing operations are based on FFT and there are tons of other purposes ... So to answer your question FFT in CS is like `+,-,*,/` in simple programing or math.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fourier transform is one of the brilliant algorithms and it has quite a lot of use cases. Signal processing is the significant one among them.

Here are some use cases:

1. You can separate a song into its individual frequencies & boost
   the ones you care for
2. Used for compression (audio for instance)
3. Used to predict earth quakes
4. Used to analyse DNA
5. Used to build apps like Shazam which predict what song is playing
6. Used in kinesiology to predict muscle fatigue by analysing muscle signals. 
   (In short, the signal frequency variations can be fed to a
   machine learning algorithm and the algorithm could predict the type of 
   fatigue and so on)

I guess, this will give you an idea of how important it is.

Comment: Do you have more info about to use the Fourier series to predict earth quakes?